# Strange issue with Cron not working

Tags: cron, log

I am having a very unusual issue at the moment with a cron task not working. In the table cron_schedule, it marks the executed_at time but never a finished_at time.

What makes this unusual is that I can get this to work fine, by placing a Mage::log() in the code.

**DOESN'T WORK**

```
function exportNewOrders()
{
    if( ! Mage::helper('warehouse/sales')->isExportEnabled() || ! Mage::helper('warehouse')->shouldRunCronJob('orders_export')) return;

    $_collection = $this->getOrdersCreatedSinceLastExport();

    // Don't generate xml if no new orders found
    if( ! count($_collection)) return;

    $_csv = Mage::getModel('warehouse/csv_order_export');

    foreach( $_collection as $_order )
    {
        $_csv->addOrder($_order);
    }
    $filename = Mage::helper('warehouse/file')->getFilename('orderexport');

    $result = $_csv->saveCsv($filename);

    if(!$result)
    {
        $this->getDebugHelper()->log( $this->getHelper()->__( 'Unable to write orders export to %s - writing error', $filename ));
    }
    else
    {
        $this->getDebugHelper()->log( $this->getHelper()->__( 'Wrote orders export to %s', $filename ));
        $this->setLastDate('sales_last_export');
        Mage::helper('warehouse/file')->setLastFileId(Mage::helper('warehouse/file')->getLastFileId() + 1);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**DOES WORK**

```
function exportNewOrders()
{
    if( ! Mage::helper('warehouse/sales')->isExportEnabled() || ! Mage::helper('warehouse')->shouldRunCronJob('orders_export')) return;

    $_collection = $this->getOrdersCreatedSinceLastExport();
    Mage::log('hello', null, 'lu.log', true); //SEE THIS LINE

    // Don't generate xml if no new orders found
    if( ! count($_collection)) return;

    $_csv = Mage::getModel('warehouse/csv_order_export');

    foreach( $_collection as $_order )
    {
        $_csv->addOrder($_order);
    }
    $filename = Mage::helper('warehouse/file')->getFilename('orderexport');

    $result = $_csv->saveCsv($filename);

    if(!$result)
    {
        $this->getDebugHelper()->log( $this->getHelper()->__( 'Unable to write orders export to %s - writing error', $filename ));
    }
    else
    {
        $this->getDebugHelper()->log( $this->getHelper()->__( 'Wrote orders export to %s', $filename ));
        $this->setLastDate('sales_last_export');
        Mage::helper('warehouse/file')->setLastFileId(Mage::helper('warehouse/file')->getLastFileId() + 1);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see I am doing no extra logic, except for this log, however this now allows the cron task to complete and gives a finished_at time. I have replicated this 100% with several tests.

Anyone come across something similar? Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can it may be that the cron has different permissions and isn't allowed to write the log file and therefor crashing? Try running the script from the shell, does that offer some insight?

Comment: How to you call the cron? Is it executed automatically or manually via cron.sh? Does that make a difference?

Comment: http://www.ecomus.co.uk/magento-running-a-cron-job-manually/ Can you try to run your cron manually ?

But this is really weird I have to say.

Comment: If the finsihed_at time is never set and the cron stays in a "running" status, it typically means it's dying due to a PHP level error. Check your PHP error logs.

Comment: Are all the standard Magento Crons working and showing a finish time? Do you clean up the failed cron jobs?

Answer (score 1):

A Cron Job with no `finished_at` time, it probably never finished.

You should find something in your error logs.

Also it helps to use the module http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html to debug, as it allows to call your cron directly from cli via:
`php shell/scheduler.php -action runNow -code productimporter_import_xml`